# Not sure what is wrong with this code for Python for Everybody 5.2

Tags: python

I'm taking Coursera and doing a python course.
I'm struggling with the last assignment.

Here is the assignment:
5.2 Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

My code:

```
# largest = None
# smallest = None
  store=[]

while True:
s = input("Enter a number: ")
if s == "done":
    break

try:
    store.append(int(s))
except:
    print("Invalid input")

largest = max(store)
smallest = min(store)
# print("Invalid input")
print("Maximum is ",largest)
print("Minimum is ",smallest)
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What is your question?  Right now all you've said is that you wrote some code.  What precisely is it that doesn't work about your code which you need help with?

Comment: If the problem is, that it stops running after entering one number: Your indentation is wrong, everything after `while True:`  and before `largest = max(store)` needs to be indented, but I guess that could be from pasting it into Stackoverflow as well.

Comment: The output of the assignment is supposed to be                                               Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2                                                                                                      I get the same output but it still says that it's wrong.     It says "Maximum is  10 ← Mismatch"

Comment: make sure to give 4 space indentation it is probably the indentation mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
store=[]

while True:
    s = input("Enter a number: ")
    if s == "done":
        break

    try:
        store.append(int(s))
    except:
        print("Invalid input")

largest = max(store)
smallest = min(store)

print("Maximum is ",largest)
print("Minimum is ",smallest)
```